# Reset whole Flex application - all form fields and other user data (without URLRequest/Javascript)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

What are the best practices to reset multi user Flex applications?
With reset i mean:

- Reset all form fields and other data the user left throughout the application during his session
- Reset all datagrids and other components containing specific data

...when the user logs out of the application.

I know the approaches of doing an URL reload with navigateToURL, or by using Javascript. But i don't like these approaches. Mainly because the whole application has to be loaded again, which costs its time and is a bit brute for just resetting data.

Are there any nice alternative approaches which don't require a URL reload?

Answer (score 2):

Write a method for setting your app into the default state; whatever that is.  Run that as part of the log out procedure.

If you're looking for some automatic way to do that, I can't think of one.  How would the person writing such an 'automatic' algorithm know what your defaults would be?

Answer (score 1):

First, @www.Flextras.com is right... "default" state is defined by you, the application developer.  If you don't want to reload the app to start over, you need to know what it means to clear out all of the fields.  He is absolutely correct and he gets a +1.

That being said, I can add a few more ideas for you to brainstorm.  You can always write a routine that navigates the visual tree using functions like `getElement` and `numElements` recursively.  You can do something like assume that all TextInputs and TextAreas are to be cleared and clear them when you find them in the tree.  You could even go as far is create a configuration files that lists the fields by name in the tree and the default values.  You could then traverse the tree, finding elements by name, and setting them to defaults defined in your config.

BUT, you are still left being in charge of knowing what the default state looks like and what to clear.  From a Flex perspective, a property is a property.  TextInput.text is no more special than BorderContainer.backgroundAlpha.  If such a thing existed to set everything to "default", then your app would come crumbling down on itself.  So, figure out what it means to be "default" or "reset" in your app.  Encapsulate that definition somehow, so it isn't peppered throughout your code, and apply your clearing algorithm of choice.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Currently i think about looping through all uicomponents in my app, and having some conventions when and how to clean form elements. Or maybe to let all "cleanable" components subclass an Interface which defines how to cleanup the component. But still i ask if there is an easier way, as i just want to have the same state that my app had at the very beginning (which is pretty well-defined!). Is there really no trick, like just re-instantiating the parent application - as then i would have the same state as in the beginning?

Comment: Sure, you can always re-instantiate the app.  Make your main form do nothing but include the guts of your app as a separate class.  Host it in a group or something.  Create a new one when you want to reset.  Remove the old one (Group.removeElement) and add the new one (Group.addElement).  As long as the new app comes with clean state, you should be all set.  Also, make sure your old app gets garbage collected.  You certainly don't want to keep them around when they are not being used.

Comment: Hmm, this way, i cannot forget to reset any form element. Ill try that in a few days, but it sounds like a very promising approach!